# Generating number pairs satisfying conditions

Tags: expression-manipulation, regions, sets

I would like to create a list of tuples $(m,k)$ satisfying the conditions

$\qquad 26\leq m\leq 500$, $k^2 (m - k)^2 \leq m (m - 1) (3 k + m)$ and $\sqrt{2m}-1/2\leq k\leq \sqrt{2}m$.

```
Table[If[26 < m < 500; k^2 (m - k)^2 < m (m - 1) (3 k + m), {m, k}], 2]
```

doesn't work. What should I do?

#### Edit

I left out one of my conditions because I was just trying to get something to work quickly. I was going to add the other later.

Comment: Please format your code (put it in a code block).  Your `If` syntax is incorrect.  Why did you use a `;` between the conditions instead of `&&`?  The `Table` syntax is also incorrect.  *Don't just guess, look up the syntax in the documentation!*

Comment: I tried it with ``&&`` too, but I just couldn't make it work. Couldn't find anything with multiple conditions in an if statement.

Comment: Also from the `If` documentation: 
"If the condition is neither True nor False, If remains unevaluated:
`If[a < b, 1, 0]`
`(*If[a < b, 1, 0]*)`
".  Also try http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalAndLogicalOperators.html for more logical operator details.

Comment: Again, don't try randomly, look it up:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html  What is your intention with `Table[..., 2]`?  Why did you use `2`?  How does your choice of `2` relate to what the documentation says about the second argument of `Table`?

Comment: `Flatten[#, 1] &@
 Table[If[k^2 (m - k)^2 <= m (m - 1) (3 k + m), {m, k}, Nothing], {m, 
   26, 500}, {k, Ceiling[Sqrt[2 m] - 1/2], Floor[Sqrt[2] m]}]` gives $30268$ pairs. And this: `RegionPlot[
 k^2 (m - k)^2 <= m (m - 1) (3 k + m) && 
  Sqrt[2 m] - 1/2 <= k < Sqrt[2] m, {m, 26, 500}, {k, 0, 600}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]` shows the region of interest.

Comment: @corey979 thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@corey gave the obvious answer in the comments. That is the way I would usually use.

If you are completely new to programming, I recommend:

- https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/

I will show a less obvious and more mathematically oriented way:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[26 < m < 500 && k^2 (m - k)^2 < m (m - 1) (3 k + m), {k, m}];

solution = Solve[{m, k} \[Element] region, {m, k}, Integers];

ListPlot[{m,k} /. solution]
```

This is very inefficient, but it may be more accessible as it states the problem directly, and leaves the solution method up to Mathematica.

You can also get an (approximate) plot of all real numbers satisfying the constraints:

```
RegionPlot[region]
```

Recommended reading:

- [How to use results from Solve](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505)
- [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)
- [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)
- [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)
- [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)
- [`RegionBounds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBounds.html)

Comment: What about the condition `Sqrt[2 m] - 1/2 <= k <= Sqrt[2] m`?

Answer (score 1):

I think corey979's comment needs to be put on record.

**Finding integer lattice points**

```
pts = 
  Catenate @
    Table[
      If[k^2 (m - k)^2 <= m (m - 1) (3 k + m), {m, k}, Nothing], 
      {m, 26, 500}, {k, Ceiling[Sqrt[2 m] - 1/2], Floor[Sqrt[2] m]}];

SeedRandom[42]; sample = RandomSample[pts, 10]
```

> `{{298, 265}, {85, 77}, {172, 178}, {114, 130}, {33, 24}, 
>   {470, 451}, {413, 421}, {348, 330}, {278, 244}, {313, 344}}`

```
r = 
  ImplicitRegion[
    k^2 (m - k)^2 <= m (m - 1) (3 k + m) && Sqrt[2 m] - 1/2 <= k <= Sqrt[2] m, 
    {{m, 26, 500}, {k, 0, 600}}];
```

Checking that the points, `pts`, lie in the region, `r`.

```
AllTrue[pts, RegionMember[r]]
```

> `True`

**Visualizing the region**

```
DiscretizeRegion[r, Frame -> True]
```

[image: region]